# statement requires expression of scalar type

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have this If statement and i keep getting this error

> statement requires expression of scalar type(CGRec(aka struct CGRect) invalid)

```
    -(void)checkCollision
{
    if (CGRectIntersection(player.frame, spot.frame))
    {
        [spot setHidden:YES];
    }


}
```

"player" and "spot" are both

```
IBOutlet UIImageView *player;
IBOutlet UIImageView *spot;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CGRectIntersectsRect` not `CGRectIntersection`.

`CGRectIntersectsRect` returns a boolean value: `YES` if the rectangles intersect. `CGRectIntersection` returns the `CGRect`.

I hope this will be helpful.

Comment: Thats right my bad didn't see that this had already been answered thanks guys.